# RadioButtonList alignment issue

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a below code based  on the value from backend i have to display the radiobuttonlist listitem value and controls in aspx page.

when the rbl1.SelectedValue = "0" the alignmnet of the controls are fine. 
 when the rbl1.SelectedValue = "1" the  RadioButtonList is coming to center like below, and i want this rbl to align left side only.

can any body help me in this.

- C#:

  ```
  public string HiddenClassName { get; private set; }
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.ToLower() == "y")
  {
      rbl1.SelectedValue = "0"; //Yes                 
      lblName.Visible = true;
      txtName.Visible = true;               
      HiddenClassName = "display:block";
  }
  else
  {
      rbl1.SelectedValue = "1"; //No
      lblName.Visible = false;
      txtName.Visible = false;
      HiddenClassName = "display:none";
  }
  ```
- ASPX:

  ```
      <h2>
           Information</h2>
      <table width="100%">
          <tr>
              <td>
                  <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Width="180px" Text="Would like to use?"></asp:Label>
              </td>
              <td >
                  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl1" runat="server" TextAlign="Right" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                      <asp:ListItem Value="Yes" Text="Yes" Selected="True" />
                      <asp:ListItem Value="No" Text="No" />
                  </asp:RadioButtonList>
              </td>
              <td style="padding-bottom: 17px">
                      <%=this.ShowHelp("rbl_Help")%>
                  </td>
            <%--  <asp:Panel ID="pnlAgntName" runat="server">  --%>                      
                  <td align="right">
                      <asp:Label ID="lblName" Text="Name" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                  </td>
                  <td align="left">
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                  </td>
                  <td  style="<%= HiddenClassName %>;padding-bottom: 17px">
                      <%=this.ShowHelp("Name_Help")%>
                  </td>
              <%--</asp:Panel>--%>
          </tr>               
      </table>
      <div class="hr">
      </div>
  </fieldset>
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add width in each td like style="width: 25px"